# Load only small subset of messages

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms

I have thousands upon thousands of text/picture messages on my Samsung Galaxy S 2, ice cream sandwich. When I go to open a conversation, the phone stops for a good 30 seconds, even after a fresh reboot. I don't want to delete my messages, but I'm sure if I could somehow limit it to, say, the last 100 messages by default, it would load much quicker. Again, I don't want to delete them, and I still need access to most of the messages, but only on demand

Comment: Are you using the stock SMS app? If so, have you considered using alternatives like Handcent or GoSMS and seeing if their performance differs from the stock app?

Comment: @Sparx I did not know that there existed alternatives... Do they completely take over the system? Or do I need to restart all the conversations?

Comment: Try them out one at a time. Ideally go to the settings of the stock app and disable notifications there to avoid duplicate notifications. Handcent / GoSMS will handle notifications, popups and custom tones far better than the default app.

Comment: @Sparx I will try out Handcent (good reviews), but GoSMS has lots of people hating on it

Comment: Both apps have cycles - at times, Handcent works better and at other times it's Go. Both have different features too, so try them out at your leisure.

Comment: Hand cent is doing the job quite well. Make an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an alternative to the stock SMS app like Handcent SMS. A cautionary note - turn off the auto delete option (the option to auto delete messages older than X days).

An additional note - since your SMS store seems quite precious to you, I'd also recommend [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore). It can backup your SMS at scheduled intervals and also email /  upload them to Dropbox if need be.